# Can I disable issuer validation upon resource server startup?

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to set up a resource server using Spring Security and now I want to run it on my machine which has to go through a SSH tunnel to reach the token issuer, so the URI my app ends up calling is something like `http://localhost:1234/.well-known/openid-configuration`. This endpoint, however, returns something like `https://my-auth-server.my-domain.com` for the `issuer` and that creates problems when the framework attempts to check that the two URIs are equal during startup.

I've been able to track it down to `JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtils` where this check happens but I just can't find any hooks to manipulate it:

- `JwtDecoders` doesn't expose any properties that instructs it to *not* validate the `issuer` on startup ([source file](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/oauth2/oauth2-jose/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/jwt/JwtDecoders.java#L103)).
- `JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtil` uses its own private `RestTemplate` so I can't add any interceptors to it.
- `JwtDecoderProviderConfigurationUtil` is package-private so I can't access any of its methods in order to compose my own version of the `JwtDecoder`.

I'd be happy to receive any pointers about how I can get around this! I'd rather not have to duplicate a whole bunch of code just to get this to work.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: No, I'm afraid not. In my case, circumstances changed so it ended up not being a problem after all.

Comment: How to you change your circumstance? I am also facing the same iseue! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom JwtDecoder which does not include the: JwtIssuerValidator

```
OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> defaultValidators = JwtValidators.createDefault()
```

Below is an e.g. if you wanted to create it with your own issuer URL you want to validate i.e. using the

```
OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> defaultValidators = JwtValidators
        .createDefaultWithIssuer("http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/CryptoInc");
```

i.e.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and()
        .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().oauth2ResourceServer()
                .jwt()
                    .decoder(jwtTokenDecoder());
}

private JwtDecoder jwtTokenDecoder() {
    NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport decoder = (NimbusJwtDecoderJwkSupport)
            JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation("http://localhost:8081/auth/realms/CryptoInc");
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> defaultValidators = JwtValidators
            .createDefault();
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> delegatingValidator = 
            new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(defaultValidators, new CryptoJwtTokenValidator());
    decoder.setJwtValidator(delegatingValidator);
    return decoder;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't fix the problem because your code still uses `JwtDecoders.withProviderConfiguration` which is where this check happens - it's not the `JwtIssuerValidator` that fails.